# is it possible to send both ReplyKeybaordMarkup and InlineKeyboardmarkup with one message in telegram bot api

Tags: php, api, php-telegram-bot

currently i have this but it just sent the 'ReplyKeyboardMarkup'

```
['chat_id' => 'BlaBlaBla',
 'text' => 'a',
 'reply_markup' => [
     'keyboard' => [[['text' => 'this is reply', 'request_contact' => true ]]] ,
     'inline_keyboard' => [[['text' => 'this is inline' , 'url' => 'BlaBlaBla' ]]]
     ]
]
```

and this the api if it helps

```
https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/sendmessage?&reply_markup={"keyboard":[[{"text":"this is reply","request_contact":true}]],"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"this is inline","url":"BlaBlaBla"}]]}&text=a&type=message&chat_id=BlaBlaBla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer is **no**.
telegram API document doesn't directly says you can't do this but according to my many research and testing there is no way you can send both of 'reply keyboard' & 'inline button' in one message **till now (2021/07/07)** .

Comment: my tests also fail by today.